# Crystal adding element to array

Tags: arrays, crystal-lang

How do you add an element to an array in Crystal ?

I tried :

```
var = Array(Int32)
var << 42 # error : undefined method '<<'
var += 42 # error : undefined method '+'
var.add(42) # error : undefined method 'add'
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Is it even possible to dynamically add elements to an array ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that you're not initializing the class. `var = Array(Int32)` should be either of these:

```
var = Array(Int32).new
# or
var = [] of Int32
```

And then append to it with:

```
var << 42
```

What you're currently doing is creating a reference to the `Array` class, which you can then use to perform some type checks, among other things. For example:

```
ref = Array(Int32)
arr = [] of Int64

puts typeof(arr) == ref # false
```

Comment: well, it sure does help XD. Thanks ^^

Comment: I'm trying to do this for an array of TCPSocket objects and I'm still getting the no such method append error.